# Linker error "unresolved external symbol __imp___iob_func" in libpng.lib

Tags: c, windows-mobile, libpng

I am trying to compile libpng for Windows Mobile 6, but i kep getting the following linker errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___iob_func referenced in function png_default_error libpng.lib
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_abort referenced in function png_longjmp
```

Compilation is done with /MD option, same between my main project. zlib and libpng.

When /MT is used instead, there are still errors, but slightly different:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __iob_func referenced in function png_default_error
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol abort referenced in function png_longjmp
```

That brings several questions.

1. What are `__imp___iob_func` and `__imp_abort`?
2. Where are they implemented at? Alternatively, how can a reference to them be excluded?

My libpng compiler options:

```
/Od /I "..\lib\zlib-1.2.7" /I "..\lib\lpng1512" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WIN32_WCE=0x502" /D "UNDER_CE" /D "WIN32_PLATFORM_PSPC" /D "WINCE" /D "DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "LIBPNG_EXPORTS" /D "ARM" /D "_ARM_" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /MDd /fp:fast /GR- /Fo"Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK (ARMV4I)\Debug/" /Fd"Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK (ARMV4I)\Debug/vc80.pdb" /W3 /nologo /c /Zi /TC /QMFPE-
```

librarian options:

```
/OUT:"Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK (ARMV4I)\Debug\libpng.lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\PocketPC\Lib\Armv4i" /NOLOGO /NODEFAULTLIB Coredll.lib /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWSCE,5.02
```

My project (libpngStreamWrap) compiler options:

```
/Od /I "..\lib\lpng1512" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WIN32_WCE=0x502" /D "UNDER_CE" /D "WIN32_PLATFORM_PSPC" /D "WINCE" /D "DEBUG" /D "_LIB" /D "ARM" /D "_ARM_" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /D "_WINDLL" /Gm /EHsc /MDd /fp:fast /GR- /Yu"stdafx.h" /Fp"Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK (ARMV4I)\Debug/libpngStreamWrap.pch" /Fo"Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK (ARMV4I)\Debug/" /Fd"Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK (ARMV4I)\Debug/vc80.pdb" /W3 /nologo /c /Zi /TP
```

linker options:

```
/OUT:"Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK (ARMV4I)\Debug\libpngStreamWrap.dll" /NOLOGO /DLL /MANIFEST:NO /NODEFAULTLIB:"oldnames.lib" /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT coredll.lib corelibc.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib commctrl.lib "..\libpng\windows mobile 6 professional sdk (armv4i)\debug\libpng.lib" "..\zlib\windows mobile 6 professional sdk (armv4i)\debug\zlib.lib"  /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWSCE,5.02 /VERBOSE:lib
```

Comment: They are functions that are imported from the DLL version of the C runtime library.  Getting linker errors for them would indicate that libpng was compiled wrong.  Wrong header files or wrong compiler settings (/MT vs /MD option).  Rebuild libpng and ensure that all compiler settings match with your main project.

Comment: Posted errors with both /MT and /MD options.

Comment: Can you post your compiler and linker command lines?

Answer (score 5):

This has been discussed recently on the png-mng-implement list
at sourceforge.net (topic libpng Visual Studio 2010 project):

> After several long googling sessions it turned out that the reason was
>   that libpng debug profile "Runtime library" setting is not set to
>   "Multi-threaded Debug DLL" as excepted, but instead to "Multi-threaded
>   DLL", which is the same profile as used in the release build.

This is a bug.  It seems to be a result of a bad hand edit to the
vcxproj project files - if the RuntimeLibrary element is removed or
invalid it gets set to the default, which is /MD for a DLL.

It could be fixed in libpng 1.5, but that would be an API change and
would break existing, working, libpng 1.5 projects.  Consequently I
think the best thing is to add a warning notice (probably in a
separate file WARNING) to projects/vstudio pointing out the problem.
It's easy for people to change the setting once they know it is
potentially wrong.

Comment: I am working in Visual Studio 2008, though.

Anyway, i managed to build it all eventually. Will post details later.