# How can I fix LNK2001/2005 issues?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

I got lots of LNK2001/2005 issues inside Visual C++ 2000 Express:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: lice, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(518,5): error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v140) is not installed or invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is selected.
2>------ Build started: Project: IPlug, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(518,5): error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v140) is not installed or invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is selected.
3>------ Build started: Project: MyFirstPlugin-app, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>asio.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/INCREMENTAL:NO' specification
3>LIBCMTD.lib(sprintf.obj) : error LNK2005: _sprintf already defined in IPlug.lib(IPlugBase.obj)
3>LIBCMTD.lib(vsprintf.obj) : error LNK2005: __vsprintf_l already defined in IPlug.lib(IPlugBase.obj)
3>IPlug.lib(IPopupMenu.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)
3>lice.lib(lice_png.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)
3>lice.lib(lice.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl _LICE_Template_Blit2<class _LICE_CombinePixelsMulSourceAlphaClamp>::scaleBlit(unsigned char *,unsigned char *,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int)" (?scaleBlit@?$_LICE_Template_Blit2@V_LICE_CombinePixelsMulSourceAlphaClamp@@@@SAXPAE0HHHHHHHHHHHH@Z)
3>lice.lib(lice_textnew.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)
3>IPlug.lib(IPlugBase.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)
3>IPlug.lib(IGraphicsWin.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)
3>IPlug.lib(IGraphics.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)
3>IPlug.lib(IControl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)
3>IPlug.lib(IPlugBase.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vfprintf referenced in function __vfprintf_l
3>lice.lib(pngerror.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vfprintf
3>IPlug.lib(IParam.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
3>IPlug.lib(IPlugBase.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf referenced in function __vsnprintf_l
3>IPlug.lib(Log.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
3>IPlug.lib(IPlugStructs.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
3>IPlug.lib(IGraphicsWin.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
3>IPlug.lib(IPlugBase.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsscanf referenced in function __vsscanf_l
3>IPlug.lib(Log.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __Init_thread_header referenced in function "char const * __cdecl AppendTimestamp(char const *,char const *,char const *)" (?AppendTimestamp@@YAPBDPBD00@Z)
3>lice.lib(lice_textnew.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __Init_thread_header
3>IPlug.lib(Log.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __Init_thread_footer referenced in function "char const * __cdecl AppendTimestamp(char const *,char const *,char const *)" (?AppendTimestamp@@YAPBDPBD00@Z)
3>lice.lib(lice_textnew.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __Init_thread_footer
3>IPlug.lib(Log.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __Init_thread_epoch
3>lice.lib(lice_textnew.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __Init_thread_epoch
3>IPlug.lib(IGraphicsWin.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___report_rangecheckfailure referenced in function "void __cdecl GetModulePath(struct HINSTANCE__ *,class WDL_String *)" (?GetModulePath@@YAXPAUHINSTANCE__@@PAVWDL_String@@@Z)
3>lice.lib(pngerror.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___report_rangecheckfailure
3>lice.lib(pngrutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___report_rangecheckfailure
3>lice.lib(inftrees.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___report_rangecheckfailure
3>lice.lib(pngerror.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___acrt_iob_func referenced in function _png_default_error
3>lice.lib(pngget.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __dtoui3 referenced in function _png_get_pHYs_dpi
3>build-win\app\Win32\bin\MyFirstPlugin.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 3 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I don't know where they come from. I'm following [this](http://www.martin-finke.de/blog/articles/audio-plugins-002-setting-up-wdl-ol/#windows_setup) tutorial to setup my environment for making audio plugin. As suggested in the tutorial, I've set `"Properties → Linker (General) → Enable Incremental Linking → “No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)”"` but without any success. I've also setup SP1.

Any helps? I've also tried with Visual Studio 2015, but I got other problems too. So its better first fit to the tutorial... but I can't go forward with these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it, you've three different kinds of linker error here - and hopefully one single fix.

`error LNK2005: _sprintf already defined in IPlug.lib(IPlugBase.obj)`
This error suggests that the library in question (IPlug.lib) has been [compiled using a different runtime-library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12943895/2810883) linking (static or dynamic , debug or release) [This link describes the compiler-settings for these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx). You'll need to identify the correct setting so that **your project matches the library being linked**

```
IPlug.lib(IPlugBase.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vfprintf referenced in function __vfprintf_l
```

This appears (though may not be) that due to the previous error, the runtime-library hasn't been linked, and thus it's components (such as fprintf) are not available to be linked. **this should be solved by fixing the previous issue**

```
lice.lib(inftrees.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___report_rangecheckfailure
lice.lib(pngerror.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___acrt_iob_func referenced in function _png_default_error
```

These two issues appear to be actual unresolved symbols, these will *hopefully* be solved by repairing the first issue - if not, you'll be missing a library needed by your project. Study the documentation until you find it.

## Update

After some effort, it was discovered the OP has missed the step of using `git checkout` in the tutorial he was following, as such the library he was linking against was not compatible with his version of Visual-Studio

Comment: I've tried to change all `Runtime Library property` from the link you have suggested to me, and press F5 every time I've changed it. But I got the same results every time. Should I "clean" somethings? Or what I need to do more?

Comment: Using `/MT`, now it also says `3>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
3>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library`

Comment: That warning can (in this case) be safely ignored. @markzzz

Comment: In any case, the rest of error keep on the log, using 4 different Runtime Library: Multi-threaded (/MT), Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd), Multi-threaded DLL (/MD), Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd). These are what I can use. Are there any other settings? :O

Comment: @markzzz it's possible the library itself is at fault - Did you compile the library from source? Do you have the option to do that?

Comment: Its official from here: http://www.steinberg.net/en/company/developers.html I don't think they put "fault" library. It's a common library...

Comment: @markzzz I don't mean the library itself is "faulty" I mean that the "fault" is in the library: IE, it was compiled with a version of visual studio that isn't compatible with the one you are using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107124/discussion-between-markzzz-and-john-bargman).